# put reminders in all events android calendar

Tags: android, events, calendar, reminders

Hi I'm trying to put reminders to all events that I have inserted a calendar that I created. Can this be done? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This example adds a reminder to an event. The reminder fires 10 minutes before the event.

And add an event and a reminder this way:

```
// get calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// event insert
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", "Reminder Title");
values.put("allDay", 0);
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
values.put("description", "Reminder description");
values.put("visibility", 0);
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

// reminder insert
Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
values = new ContentValues();
values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put( "method", 1 );
values.put( "minutes", 10 );
cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

You'll also need to add these permission to your manifest for this method:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: getCalendarUriBase returns null